# stoping access to other pages without signin

Tags: php, html

i am creating a list of webpages ..the first webpage is 'login.html  and then 'detail.html'  and 'signout option'.. but i need some help that how to stop myself from opening 'detail.html' if i am not singed in through 'login.html'. i need start. please help me .thanks in advance.

```
login.html---

    <form> 
    <input type="text" name= "username" size="15" />
    <input type="password" name= "passwrd" size="15" />
    <input name="submit" type = "button" onClick = "login('login.php','msg',username.value,passwrd.value)"  value = "Login" /> 
    </form>  
    <div id="msg"></div>

// here is the signout as menu option in details.html page


<ul>      

     <li><a href="newitem.html" title="newitem">New Item</a></li>
     <li><a href="updateitem.html" title="updateitem">Update Item</a></li>
         <div id="one"><a href='signout.php'>Signout</a></div>
</ul>   

signout.php---

<?php

include("login.html");  

?> 

//if login then 
 { 
          echo "detailpage.html";
 }
```

Comment: You *do* realize that `login.html` doesn't actually sign you in, right?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams  you are 100% right. because in my code if username and password are correct then  { 
          echo "detailpage.html";
         }

Comment: Then you need to complete your question so that we can know how to tell that one is logged in.

Comment: Whatever you try next (find a PHP intro tutorial) you should rename the `.html` pages into `.php` to get your code to work. Something tells me there isn't much PHP usage yet.

Comment: @mario: What for? They're plain HTML pages.

Answer (score 0):

in the login page use `session_start();` on the top of the page, and set some session variable for the login page, and check that variable in every- page like

> for login page

```
session_start();
//do some login validations

$_SESSION['login'] = true;
```

for the other pages check this session variable is set or not like

```
//for other pages
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['login']) && $_SESSION == true)
{
  //your code here
}
else{
 echo 'Access Denied!';
 exit();
}
```

Comment: @carina, you have to use first code on login.php file, and never forget to start a session before assigning the session variable

Comment: i used it in login.php file   but as the main page is detail.html , so how can i use session variable there?

Comment: @carina, i see in above code you check if login then echo 'detail.html', just use if login and after that check if isset session variable then echo 'detail.html' else echo 'access denied!'

Comment: yes if it is not set then it doesnt go to detail.html  but i can access 'detail.html' by using path in address bar of browser

Comment: @carina, if you want to not access the 'detail.html' before login then just change the extension of 'detail.html' to 'detail.php' and check the session variable cause the php codes will not work in simple html file but the html code will correctly work in .php file

Answer (score 0):

you have to manage the login using session or cookies in login.html then you need to check the login session for the details if the session is exists then you can give the view permission to user or redirect user to login.html to login